# Django no entry in many to many table

Tags: django, django-admin, many-to-many

I have a problem with django that I really cant get my head around. Been stuck on it for two days and been looking in the source but I cant find any explanation, hopefully someone knows this better than I do!

I have two models, `Publication` and `Article` like this

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    articles = models.ManyToManyField('Article',blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'publications'

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
         db_table = 'articles'
```

When I save a new `Publication` I want to automatically save a default article. I did a script to test this and it works fine. Both objects are created in their respective tables and one entry is written to the `publications_articles` table. As expected.

```
publication = Publication(title='The new exciting publication')
publication.save()
publication.articles.create(headline='The article that makes the pub so exciting')
```

However, here is the tricky part. To have the same functionality when saving a `Publication` in the admin I did override the `save_model()` function like this.

```
class PublicationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title']

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change:
            obj.save()
            obj.articles.create(headline='The article that makes this pub so exciting')
        else:
            obj.save()
```

Saving a `Publication` in the admin creates both the `Publication` and the `Article` but theres no entry in the `publications_articles` table tying them together!

Someone please, please explain this behavior. I'm about to do a raw sql-insert just to get through with it but I want to understand why the connection between the entities is not made.

Comment: are you sure that the flow enters `if not change:` case?

Comment: I've ran your code (with the addition of `admin.site.register(Publication, PublicationAdmin)` and it works like charm (Django version 1.3.4, Python 2.6). Could it be that there is more code that might prevent your code from working? Try to add some `print "test"` statements to your `save_model(...)` and see if the code is actually executed. Another test: insert `print obj.pk` inbetween `obj.save()` and `obj.articles.create(..`

Comment: Probably, he should have missed the `admin.site.register` part.

Comment: you can do a `new Article` and then `.add` to the m2m field

Comment: @Babu, yes it does. I cleaned the code up, had dozens of `prints`.

Comment: @Karthikr, tried that one during my two day stint as well and got the same result before. Works in script but not in the admin.

Comment: @Wouter Klein Heerenbrink, the pk:s are generated no problem since the objects are created and saved in their respective table. Had a few lines of debugs here before. Interesting that you got it working, I´m running 1.4.3. I did try to use the signal interface and save the `Article` there, but the result was just the same. It seems like something just doesnt run the code that saves the m2m relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you debug through the code at the end of your `save_model`, you will notice that `save_related` is called right after.  This method checks the entered `Publication` form for any form entered related data.  Since article was added through the code, it will not commit any values to the database in the `publications_articles` table.

At the end of the overriden `save_model` method, you will also notice `obj.articles.count()` returning 1 but no values has been inserted in the table at this point.

It might be best to override `save_related`:

```
def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
    form.save_m2m()
    for formset in formsets:
        self.save_formset(request, form, formset, change=change)

    if not change and not formsets 
        form.instance.articles.create(headline='The article that makes this pub so exciting')
```

Comment: Cheers! That resolved it. I still dont quite understand why this does work and the other didnt. I´m using the same method in the script and the only other difference is the context.

I still had to do some editing in the `save_model()` method so I kept those changes and ran `obj.save()` before the `save_related()` is called. Thanks heaps!

Comment: You don't really need to override `save_model`, `save_related` is enough.